# Modify this method so that it is applied to all items except the last item in a form group. Angular 7 reactive form. No jquery or ngModel

Tags: forms, loops, angular7, formgroups

I have a method that applies validation based on an items value in a form group.  This method is applied to all items in the form group.  I need the last item in the form group to be excluded from this method but cannot figure out how to modify it.

In my TS file

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.initForm();
 }

 initForm() {
  this.sectionSix = this.formBuilder.group({
    medicaidOrSssi: [''],
    snap: [''],
    freeOrReducedPriceLunch: [''],
    tanf: [''],
    wic: [''],
    noneOfTheAbove: [''],
    dislocatedWorker: [''],
  }, { validator: this.selectAtleastOne });

 }
```

The method I need to change is this one

```
selectAtleastOne(c: FormGroup) {
  const selectAtleastOne = Object.values(c.value).some(Boolean);
  return selectAtleastOne ? null : {
    selectAtleastOne: {
    requiredTrue: true,
    valid: false,
    error: true
    }
  };
}
```

The first 6 items in the form group are check boxes and the last item is a dropdown.  I cannot move the last question to another form group, it needs to stay in this one.

The issue is, at least one checkbox needs to be selected. If none are selected, a validation message pops up.  The way it is behaving now is, if I do not select any checkboxes, and select a value from the dropdown (the last item in the form group), it considers the checkboxes valid, even if they are all blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit your dropdown field from the `c.value` and then check for boolean. I think that will work.

Try this.

```
selectAtleastOne(c: FormGroup) {
  const { ['dislocatedWorker']: dd, ...allCheckboxes } = c.value;
  const selectAtleastOne = Object.values(allCheckboxes).some(Boolean);
  return selectAtleastOne ? null : {
    selectAtleastOne: {
    requiredTrue: true,
    valid: false,
    error: true
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: That worked out very nicely.  Thank you for the help.